# Google Play Console: Promoted app from Alpha to Beta but still needs to Pre register

Tags: android, flutter, deployment, google-play, production

I've just promoted my Flutter app from Alpha to Beta in Play Console earlier today. But when I checked the app on Play Store, the outside email that I am using still need to pre-register (mind you that Alpha state is finished, and what I'm expecting when I promote the app to Beta, any users can download it now without the need for an invitation.)

How can I fix this? 
in the screenshots below, there's already a Beta state of the app
[image]

this second screenshot shows that my **Live Update** is already up (check it in notifications) but upon checking on Google Play or the Opt-link I still need to `Pre-register` or `Become a tester` (on PC)

> Note that before posting this question, I've already promoted it to Beta and a notification shows it is life but still I need to pre-register or become a test, I just re-released it to Beta state but even before re-releasing it to Beta, it still shows a pre-register or become a tester

[image]

[image]

> **UPDATE** Ive re-released it to beta with the 4002 included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alpha section contains an apk with a higher number (4002) than the beta section (2002). Higher version code number means more recent. If you upload an apk with version 4003 on the beta channel, it should replace the alpha.

Keep in mind that an app update can take more than a day to be fully deployed, and I think especially when you transition from version types.

Comment: Hi! Can you take a look at my updated question? (third pic) Ive added the 4002 apk also on re-releasing to Beta

Comment: I'm not sure that equal codes will make the beta take over. You would need version code 4003.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have accidentally started pre-registrations for your application. It overrides the beta build. The same issue has happened to us and we want to go back to beta from pre-registration. Also looking for help here.